# Common syntax for creating named_struct in hive and presto

Tags: hive, presto

I am trying to define a sql view that picks a subset of elements from a source struct data type and creates a new struct. In hive I can do this:

```
create view myview as 
select
    id,
    named_struct("cnt", bkg.cnt, "val", bkg.val) as bkg
from mybkgtable
```

This works. The trouble is, when this view is invoked from presto, it fails with: `Function named_struct not registered`

Found that presto has no *struct* data type, but has *ROW* instead. It works with this syntax:

```
select
    id,
    CAST(ROW(bkg.cnt, bkg.val) as row(cnt integer, val double)) as bkg
from mybkgtable
```

However, this syntax isn't understood by Hive.

Question is, is it possible to have one view definition that works on both hive and presto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question is, is it possible to have one view definition that works on both hive and presto?

Sadly, no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use coral to write the view definition in hiveql and translate it to presto.

https://github.com/linkedin/coral

https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2020/coral